# SqlDataSource rows in columns

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

My database looks like :

`````````````````
_______________
column1|column2|
name1  |  5    |
name1  |  3    |
name1  |  1    |
name2  |  2    |
name2  |  4    |
````````````````
`````````````````

Im using VS 2012 and asp:DataList, and I'm trying to show the data in this way:

``````````````````
_________________
name1 | 5 | 3 | 1|
name2 | 2 | 4 |  |
`````````````````
``````````````````

I tried a lot of several ways to do it:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:finchsize_polibudaConnectionString %>"
SelectCommand="SELECT a1.[przedmiot], a1.[ocena], a2.[ocena] from [oceny] as a1, [oceny] as a2 where a1.[ocena] != a2.[ocena] and a1.przedmiot = a2.przedmiot;">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
    <table>
        <td>
            <asp:DataList ID="DataListOcenyDzieciak" runat="server" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" RepeatColumns="1" 
        >
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="przedmiotLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("przedmiot") %>' />
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ocena") %>' />
            <br />
        </ItemTemplate>

    </asp:DataList>

        </td>
```

But it didn't work. Do you know how I should do that?

Comment: What didn't work? Did you get an error or does it just show incorrect values?

Answer (score 0):

It is funny that you expect it to render more than 2 columns after:

```
<ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="przedmiotLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("przedmiot") %>' />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ocena") %>' />
        <br />
</ItemTemplate>
```

Firstly, the data that you gave is not consistent, ie. you can't reliable repeat it in a dataview. For example, do you know how many columns of data you will have at max. If you do, then I would write a for loop and fill up a dataTable with data in the required format and attach it to the datalist.